# How to increase performance of redis sub?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, node-redis

I have code like that

```
var subscribeNewMessages = require("redis").createClient(config.redis.port, config.redis.host);
subscribeNewMessages.subscribe('new-messages');

io.of('/new-messages').on('connection', function (client) {
        subscribeNewMessages.on("message", function(channel, message) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(message);
            if (client.userId == obj.toUserId || client.guestId == obj.toUserId) {
                client.send(message);
            }
            obj = null;
        });
})
```

And how can I optimize it? Because this code parses string json for each new messages.

Also when I try to publish to redis chanel I need to JSON.stringify

```
redis1.publish(channelPrefix, JSON.stringify(clientData));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't going to be a way to avoid `JSON.parse()`/`JSON.stringify()` as long as you're storing js objects. You could use a different serialization format like msgpack, but you're still calling functions to serialize/unserialize your data (also `JSON.parse()`/`JSON.stringify()` are already pretty hard to beat performance-wise in node).

I think the only real performance adjustment you could make with the code you've provided is to only parse the JSON once for *all* clients instead of for each client. Example:

```
var subscribeNewMessages = require('redis').createClient(config.redis.port, config.redis.host);
subscribeNewMessages.subscribe('new-messages');

var nsNewMsgs = io.of('/new-messages');
subscribeNewMessages.on('message', function(channel, message) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(message),
      clients = nsNewMsgs.connected,
      ids = Object.keys(clients);
  for (var i = 0, len = ids.length, client; i < len; ++i) {
    client = clients[ids[i]];
    if (client.userId == obj.toUserId || client.guestId == obj.toUserId)
      client.send(message);
  }
});
```

Depending on your application, you might even be able to avoid the for-loop entirely if you can store the `socket.id` values in your published messages, then you can simply look up `clients[obj.userSockId]` and `clients[obj.guestSockId]` because the [`connected`](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io#namespaceconnectedobject) is keyed on [`socket.id`](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io#socketidstring).

Comment: I changed it and it became better. But application still use cpu in strange way http://oi58.tinypic.com/15o9mrd.jpg

Comment: Did you isolate the problem to this particular code so that you know it's not something else?

Comment: Please advise tool to find out bottleneck. What do you use for it?